# Populating 2 HTML Selects with 1 ASP While statement

Tags: html, asp-classic

I'm trying to populate 2  statements with data from a SQL recordset using 1 ASP While statement.

```
           <select name="startshift" id="startshift"> 
       <%     
    While Not oRSShifts.EOF
    response.Write("<option value=" & ORSShifts("Shift_Start_Time") & "> " & ORSShifts("Shift_Start_Time") & " </option>")    
    oRSShifts.MoveNext 
    WEND
    %>
    </select>
    <select name="endshift" id="endshift"> 
      <%     
    While Not oRSShifts.EOF
    response.Write("<option value=" & ORSShifts("Shift_End_Time") & "> " & ORSShifts("Shift_End_Time") & " </option>")    
    oRSShifts.MoveNext 
    WEND
    %>
    </select>
```

The problem I have is the second drop down doesn't populate - I've tried doing both in the save WHILE statement but it just creates the same amount of drop downs as there are entries in the SQL.

I've also combined both `Shift_Start_Time` and `Shift_End_Time` into one string but I really need it in 2 drop down menus if possible.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `MoveFirst()` between the two `While` loops.  As it is, the first loop finishes once the recordset reaches EOF; since you're not resetting the cursor, it's still at EOF when the second loop begins.

Alternatively, you could just read all the values into an array, ten loop through the array twice to create the option HTML.

Comment: Thanks very much, added an oRSShifts.MoveFirst before the second WHILE statement